# Cygwin FIFO vs native Linux FIFO - discrepancy in blocking behaviour?

Tags: cygwin, fifo

The code shown is based on an example using named pipes from some tutorial site

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"

int main()
{
        int fd;
        char readbuf[80];
        int read_bytes;

        // mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO|0640, 0);
        mkfifo(FIFO_FILE, 0777);
        while(1) {
                fd = open(FIFO_FILE, O_RDONLY);
                read_bytes = read(fd, readbuf, sizeof(readbuf));
                readbuf[read_bytes] = '\0';
                printf("Received string: \"%s\". Length is %d\n", readbuf, (int)strlen(readbuf));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

When executing the server in Windows, using Cygwin, then the server enters an undesired loop, repeating the same message. For example, if you write in a shell:

```
$ ./server
|
```

then the "server" waits for the client, but when the FIFO is not empty, e.g. writing in a new shell

```
$ echo "Hello" > MYFIFO
```

then the server enters an infinite loop, repeating the "Hello"-string

```
Received string: "Hello". Length is 4
Received string: "Hello". Length is 4
...
```

Furthermore, new strings written to the fifo doesn't seem to be read by the server. However, in Linux the behaviour is quite different. In Linux, the server prints the string and waits for new data to appear on the fifo. What is the reason for this discrepancy ?

Comment: How can `Hello\n` be only four bytes? Surely you can see there must be _something_ wrong with your code, even if you can't identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your code to remove at least 3 bugs:

You're not doing a `close(fd)` so you will get a file descriptor leak and eventually be unable to `open()` new files.

You're not checking the value of `fd` (if it returns `-1` then there was an error).

You're not checking the value of `read` (if it returns `-1` then there was an error)... and your `readbuf[read_bytes] = '\0';` will not be doing what you expect as a result.

When you get an error then `errno` will tell you what went wrong.

These bugs probably explain why you keep getting `Hello` output (especially the `readbuf[read_bytes]` problem).

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement a check on fd or move the open() outside of the loop to see if that makes a difference. However, the same code works fine in Ubuntu. Please realize that the code is minimum to show the concept.

Comment: The problem is that differences in behaviour can cause errors to appear and these are being masked by the lack of error handling.  Fixing the bugs will show you how the implementations differ and the `errno` value may provide hints.

Comment: Also need an upper limit for `read` of `sizeof(readbuf)-1` so that you have somewhere to write the trailing `\0`.

Comment: @roaima The link pointed from the OP's question is full of questionable stuff -- to put it mildly. I wonder what's the point of keeping it. Wouldn't be better to edit it out to something like "got this code from a tutorial site", and leave the site unnamed and unlinked?

Comment: @UncleBilly tempting isn't it. Just nearly wept to see another example completely missing the point with a "bidirectional" fifo...

Comment: I'm so glad you guys left these comments and reminded me to be more critical to online tutorials

Comment: @roaima Can you please elaborate on which point the example with a full-duplex fifo "completely misses" ? To be honest, I think the examples are quite good if you consider them to be specific on topic, but surely I'm to novice to see the subtleties ? The link was
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inter_process_communication/inter_process_communication_named_pipes.htm

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk the issues i have with that tutorial are (a) untested and buggy code teaching poor habits (see the answer and comments above) and (b) wrong descriptions of fundamental concepts, for example incorrect concept of a "full duplex fifo", which simply doesn't exist. If it did, you could have two readers and some way of identifying which writes should go to which reader. But you can't, because a fifo is inherently unidirectional.

Comment: I see. Thank you for that insight :)

Comment: To be fair, the author doesn't mention "full-duplex fifos". He writes "named pipes can have bi-directional communication" though...

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk someone else asked a [very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493343/100397) just today over on [Unix.SE]. Hope it will help.

Comment: @roaima oh, the tips provided by Stephen Harris and yourself are sufficient to get a working code. I'll check it out anyway. I think there is some small discrepancies in how Cygwin "system calls" behave compared to native Linux when dealing with fifos, but the specifics are yet unclear to me. Thanks again